# Github actions + Azure OIDC with "subject" value for any branch

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, github-actions, openid-connect

I'm using Github Actions to build some Docker images that I want to push to Azure Container Registry. I am attempting to use OIDC as an auth mechanism, based on [this GH Action](https://github.com/Azure/login#sample-workflow-that-uses-azure-login-action-using-oidc-to-run-az-cli-linux). I know the action supports other auth strategies, which I have discarded for my use case for reasons.

According to [GH docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect#configuring-the-subject-in-your-cloud-provider) the "subject" field needs to be populated based on the GH account, repo name and branch name. However, want to build Docker images for multiple branches, which seems to require one federation config per branch - not practical, IMO.

So my question is: does anyone know if it's possible (and how) to set up a single federation config with a "subject" value that would work as a wildcard of sorts, covering all branches from a give repo?

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

On AWS it is possible to use wildcards, like:

`"repo:MY_ORG/MY_REPO:*"`

but that doesn't seem to work on Azure, you can enter a wildcard in Azure Federated Credentials, but the GitHub workflow fails.  To actually need a branch is crazy, as we'd need to setup new credential config for each new git branch.

I worked around the issue by using GitHub environments.  I set an environment (called `main` but it can be called anything) and then set my workflow like this:

```
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: main
```

and then in Azure set the federated creds to use:
`Entity` of `Environment` rather than `Entity` of `Branch`

This will then work for any branch - but clearly if you use GitHub environments for other reasons this may not be viable.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, since Oct. 2022:

> ### [GitHub Actions:OpenID Connect support enhanced to enable secure cloud deployments at scale](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-18-github-actionsopenid-connect-support-enhanced-to-enable-secure-cloud-deployments-at-scale) (Oct. 2022)
>
> OpenID Connect (OIDC) support in GitHub Actions enables secure cloud deployments using short-lived tokens that are automatically rotated for each deployment.
>
> You can now use the enhanced OIDC support to [configure the `subject` claim format](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect#customizing-the-subject-claims-for-an-organization-or-repository) within the OIDC tokens, by defining a customization template at either org or repo levels.
> Once the configuration is completed, the new OIDC tokens generated during each deployment will follow the custom format.
>
> This enables organization & repository admins to standardize OIDC configuration across their cloud deployment workflows that suits their compliance & security needs.
>
> Learn more about [Security hardening your GitHub Workflows using OpenID Connect](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments).

That means, from the documentation:

> ### Customizing the subject claims for an organization or repository
>
> To help improve security, compliance, and standardization, you can customize the standard claims to suit your required access conditions.
>
> If your cloud provider supports conditions on `subject` claims, you can create a condition that checks whether the sub value matches the path of the reusable workflow, such as "`job_workflow_ref: "octo-org/octo-automation/.github/workflows/oidc.yml@refs/heads/main"`".
>
> The exact format will vary depending on your cloud provider's OIDC configuration. To configure the matching condition on GitHub, you can can use the REST API to require that the `sub` claim must always include a specific custom claim, such as `job_workflow_ref`.
> You can use the [OIDC REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/oidc) to apply a customization template for the OIDC `subject` claim; for example, you can require that the `sub` claim within the OIDC token must always include a specific custom claim, such as `job_workflow_ref`.

---

As noted by [Xiang ZHU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5095636/xiang-zhu) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71051432/github-actions-azure-oidc-with-subject-value-for-any-branch/74120321#comment136092871_74120321):

> It seems that this talks about how to add additional keys in subject, but not to remove default keys.
> And the enforcement is from Azure, not from GitHub, Azure forces the field branch name without wildcard"

This is True. While GitHub has enhanced its OIDC support to allow more customizable `subject` claims, the limitation on using wildcards for branch names appears to be an Azure-specific constraint.
If Azure's OIDC configuration enforces a strict subject format that includes the branch name, then you are bound by those rules and would need to explore Azure-specific solutions or workarounds for multi-branch deployments.
Although GitHub offers increased flexibility, the final configuration would still need to comply with Azure's OIDC policies.

Comment: it seems that this talks about how to add additional keys in subject, but not to remove default keys. And the enforcement is from Azure, not from github, Azure forces the field branch name without wildcard.

Comment: @XiangZHU True. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.